# Is the entropy change due to particle insertion/deletion the same as increasing/decreasing the volume (or pressure) for an ideal gas?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, ideal-gas, chemical-potential

**Background:**

Consider a pure monatomic ideal gas within a closed system undergoing a reversible, isothermal compression/expansion.

The fundamental thermodynamic relation is

$$d U = T d S - P d V + \mu d N$$

which may be rearranged in terms of the entropy and simplified according to our specified path:

$$dS = \frac{P}{T} dV$$

> NOTE: The internal energy for an ideal gas is $U^{IG}=U^{IG}(N,T)=\frac{3}{2}Nk_{B}T$. Because our closed system is isothermal , $\partial U = 0$.

Using the ideal gas law, we replace $\frac{P}{T}$ with $\frac{Nk_{B}}{V}$ to obtain

$$dS = \frac{Nk_{B}}{V} dV$$

Integrating this expression gives :

$$\Delta S = \int\frac{Nk_{B}}{V} dV = Nk_{B}\ln\left(\frac{V_{f}}{V^{0}}\right)$$

Rearranging our expression gives:

$$S_{f}(U^{0},V_{f},N^{0}) = S^{0} + N^{0}k_{B}\ln\left(\frac{V_{f}}{V^{0}}\right)$$

We define the concentration of our closed system, an intensive quantity, as $C = \frac{N}{V}$. This changes our integrated expression to

$$S(U^{0},V_{f},N^{0}) = S^{0} - N^{0}k_{B}\ln\left(\frac{C_{f}}{C^{0}}\right)$$

With the concentration being an intensive quantity, whether the change in concentration is due to an increase in the particle number or volume is immaterial: 1 particle in 2 cubic meters is identical to 2 particles in 4 cubic meters, etc. Thus, we have

$S(U^{0},C_{f}) = S^{0} - N^{0}k_{B}\ln\left(\frac{C_{f}}{C^{0}}\right)$

or even

$S(U^{0},P_{f}) = S^{0} - N^{0}k_{B}\ln\left(\frac{P_{f}}{P^{0}}\right)$

Because entropy is a state function, we are free to choose any path between state points. If we instead consider an ideal gas within an open system, where the concentration change is the result of an isochoric particle insertion/deletion, we should arrive at the same expression. But it appears we do not...

**Attempt:**
Consider a path, where :

1. The first step is an isothermal/isochoric particle insertion.

Let our final state be abbreviated as "B". Our entropy change may be defined as:

$$\Delta S_{0\rightarrow B} = S_{B}(U^{B},V^{0},N^{B})- S^{0}$$

Our fundamental thermodynamic relation reduces to:

$$dS_{0\rightarrow B}= \frac{3V^{0}}{2T^{0}}dP_{0\rightarrow B}-\frac{\mu(T,P)V^{0}}{k_{B}(T^{0})^{2}}dP_{0\rightarrow B}$$

2. The internal energy of our system changed as a result of the isothermal particle insertion. Therefore, we must bring our internal energy back to it's initial state. We do this by taking an isochoric expansion for which the system is closed but not isothermal.

Our entropy change may be defined as:

$$\Delta S_{B \rightarrow f} = S_{f}(U^{0},V^{0},N^{B})-S_{B}(U^{B},V^{0},N^{B})$$

Our fundamental thermodynamic expression becomes:

$$dS_{B\rightarrow f}= \frac{3}{2}k_{B}(N^{B})\frac{dP_{B \rightarrow f}}{P}$$

Integrating and summing the entropy change, we get:

$$\Delta S_{0 \rightarrow f} = \frac{3V^{0}}{2T^{0}}(P^{B}-P^{0})-\frac{V^{0}}{k_{B}(T^{0})^{2}}\int_{0}^{B} \mu(T,P)dP + \frac{3}{2} k_{B}(N^{B})ln(\frac{P_{f}}{P^{B}})$$

Using statistical mechanics, the monatomic ideal gas chemical potential is:

$$\mu(T,P)=  -k_{B}T ln \left(\frac{k_{B}T}{P}(\frac{2 \pi m k_{B} T}{h^{2}})^{\frac{3}{2}} \right) $$

Integration then gives:

$$\int_{0}^{B} \mu(T,P)dP = -k_{B}T \left( (P^{B}ln(\frac{a}{P^{B}})+P^{B})-(P^{0}ln(\frac{a}{P^{0}})+P^{0})) \right)$$

where $a = \frac{k_{B}T}{\lambda^{-3}}$ and $\lambda$ is the thermal de Broglie wavelength.

Therefore the entropy change due to particle insertion/deletion is not the same as increasing/decreasing the volume (or pressure) for an ideal gas.

**Edit: Attempt 2, using Statistical Mechanics**

Consider a simple lattice model consisting of "$V$" lattice sites and "$N$" indistinguishable, non-interacting particles. Within the microcanonical ensemble $(N,V,E)$, the entropy is given by Boltzmann's equation:

$$S = k_{B}ln\left( \Omega \right)$$

The multiplicity of states is given by:

$$\Omega = \frac{V!}{(V-N)!N!}$$

We define the concentration as $C = \frac{N}{V}$.

Consider a system of $N$=3 particles and $V$=8 lattice sites. Let us define this as our initial concentration: $C^{0} = \frac{N^{0}}{V^{0}}= \frac{3}{8}$.

Now, consider removing 2 lattice sites such that $C^{f} = \frac{N^{0}}{V^{f}}= \frac{3}{6} = \frac{1}{2}$. Let us abbreviate this change as "$A$"

Consider instead inserting 1 particle such that $C^{f} = \frac{N^{f}}{V^{0}}= \frac{4}{8} = \frac{1}{2}$. Let us abbreviate this change as "$B$"

Plugging these two cases into our expression for the multiplicity gives:

$$\Omega_{A} = \frac{6!}{(6-3)!3!} \neq \Omega_{B} = \frac{8!}{(8-4)!4!}$$

So the entropy is different depending on whether we decrease the volume or increase the particle number despite the final concentration being identical?